# Altering the Appearance of Opening Double Quotes Using Tgpagella

Tags: fonts, pdftex, algorithms, displaystyle, quotation

Consider the following code which invokes the `tgpagella` font:

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{tgpagella} % Sets tgpagella as main font.
\begin{document}
\Huge
\thispagestyle{empty}
\textbf{``This is a quote.''}
\end{document}
```

which produces

[image]

Observe the unconventional opening double quotes display.

I would like (if possible), mathematically speaking, to (1) horizontally reflect the said quotes (i.e., turn them upside down), followed by (2) vertically translate up, the upside down image back to the original starting point. This will give the pair of opening quotes a more traditional appearance.

QUESTION: Is it possible to do this with Latex; and if, so how? If not, can anyone suggest a method that will allow me, using the `tgpagella` font, to display the opening pair of double quotes conventionally; that is, the image we would get if we reflect the displayed pair of closing double quotes through a vertical axis? I am compiling with `pdflatex`.

Thank you.

Comment: Please don’t commit the type crime you propose. Zapf knew what he was doing, and these quotation marks are not unconventional. though they may be less familiar to readers in countries whose publishers favor, say, Scotch Romans.

Comment: @Thérèse A typographical faux pas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

More of a long comment to the self-answer, but aimed at suggesting a better way to do the thing, if you ***really*** want to spoil an artist's work.

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{tgpagella}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{accents}% for the bad code

\newcommand{\reflection}{%
  \raisebox{.25ex}{\reflectbox{''}}%
}
\newcommand{\reflect}[1]{\accentset{\reflection}{#1}}


\begin{document}

$\reflect{}$ This is a quote''

A $\reflect{}$ quote''

\end{document}
```

produces the following very disputable output

[image]

Can you see that the opening quotes are higher than the closing ones?

Better code:

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{tgpagella}
\usepackage{graphicx}

\newcommand{\badquotes}{\reflectbox{''}}


\begin{document}

\badquotes This is a quote''

A \badquotes quote''

\end{document}
```

[image]

The name I chose should be self-explaining. Here's the output according to Zapf's design and I have no doubt which one I prefer.

[image]

Comment: Many thanks for your answer egreg.

Answer (score 1):

There may be a better way, but since posting the question I have discovered that what I asked for---can effectively be had by invoking the `rotating` and `accents` packages, and then defining a new command, say `\reflection`, as done in the following code:

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{rotating,tgpagella,accents}

\newcommand{\reflection}{%
  \raisebox{.25ex}{\reflectbox{''}}%
}
\newcommand{\reflect}[1]{\accentset{\reflection}{#1}}

\begin{document}
\thispagestyle{empty}
\Huge
$\reflect{}$ This is a quote''
\end{document}
```

which seems to produce what was asked for:

[image]

Though, in light of an earlier comment by Thérèse, it may not be such a good idea typographically speaking.

Comment: If you look carefully, the opening quotes have a different height than the closing ones. And the spacing is really wrong. Why not, more simply, `\reflectbox{''}`? That is, if you really want to spoil an artist's work. With `A $\reflect{}$quote` you get [this (click)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/61Iwv.png)